# Проблема с преобразованием данных JSON на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Помогите передать значения из JSON-строки в список на JavaScript.

"[{"res": 1.11}, {"res": 0.0}, {"res": 1.37}, {"res": 1.8}, {"res": 5.37}, {"res": 0.16}, {"res": 90.19}]"

```
 success:function(result){         
        $("#diagram-res").html(JSON.stringify(result));
        var obj = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(obj);
        var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(result);        
        var arr = [];
        var myObject = eval('(' + obj + ')');
        for (i in myObject)
        {
          arr.append(myObject[i]["res"]);
        }
        console.log(arr);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Входные данные - это не JSON, а мясо получившееся после замены символа двойных кавычек (`"`) в JSON-строке на HTML-последовательность в шестнадцатеричном коде (`&#34;`) соответствующую этому символу.

Чтобы получить валидный JSON, надо раскодировать эти HTML-последовательности обратно в нормальные символы кавычек, например так:

```js
const shittyJson = '[{&#34;res&#34;: 1.11}, {&#34;res&#34;: 0.0}, {&#34;res&#34;: 1.37}, {&#34;res&#34;: 1.8}, {&#34;res&#34;: 5.37}, {&#34;res&#34;: 0.16}, {&#34;res&#34;: 90.19}]';

const decodeHtmlEntities = str => (
  (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.textContent
);

const realJson = decodeHtmlEntities(shittyJson),
      parsedArr = JSON.parse(realJson),
      values = parsedArr.map(v => v.res);
console.log(values);
```

Но лучше конечно будет просто не портить исходную JSON-строку...